# How to make a ToolStripMenuItem hold a variable value to be recalled later?

Tags: c++-cli

I have a form that has a MenuStrip at the top. I only have one ToolStripMenuItem called Dates. I have written code that executes when an "Add" button is clicked which adds a new menu item underneath "Dates". This menu item is named by concatenating some variables which store user input. Here is everything I have for the "Add" button click event. It all works, but I want display the same info that gets displayed in the label when the click event happens to be saved to the submenu item too. So I want to be able to click that sub-menu item that is created and be able to see what input was saved to it when the Add button is clicked.

```
    private: System::Void btnAdd_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e)
{
    //add the input to the variables
    String^ month = txtMonth->Text;
    String^ day = txtDay->Text;
    String^ year = txtYear->Text;
    double tips = Double::Parse(txtTips->Text);


    //make sure the date input is correct
    if (txtMonth->Text == "" || txtDay->Text == "" || txtYear->Text == "" || Double::Parse(month) < 1 || Double::Parse(month) > 12
        || Double::Parse(day) < 1 || Double::Parse(day) > 31 /*|| Double::Parse(year)!=*/)
    {
        //show message box
        MessageBox::Show("Please enter the date in the correct format.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons::OK,
            MessageBoxIcon::Error);
        //clear the boxes
        txtMonth->Clear();
        txtDay->Clear();
        txtYear->Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        //for the menu bar
        String^ date = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
        datesToolStripMenuItem->DropDownItems->Add(date)->Equals(date);

        //print to label
        lblPrint->Text = month + "/" + day + "/" + year + " - " + tips.ToString("c");
        //clear the boxes
        txtMonth->Clear();
        txtDay->Clear();
        txtYear->Clear();
        txtTips->Clear();
    }
}
```

FYI. I haven't written any code to do what I want to do. I just have no idea where to start for that, so I've shared what I have before that.

Comment: Is this `c++CLI`? if so then remove the `c++` tag and add the appropriate tag

Comment: I am not sure to be honest, but I changed the tag assuming you are correct.

Comment: The `Tag` property is available to store any arbitrary data in a control.  Use safe_cast when you retrieve it later.